# Errors in installing conda packages (UnavailableInvalidChannel: HTTP 404 UNAVAILABLE OR INVALID for channel conda-pkgs <file:///tmp/conda-pkgs>)

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install some packages in conda. However, I am getting this wierd looking channel (*file:///tmp/conda-pkgs*) in my channels list. This subsequently produces errors

- \ Unable to retrieve repodata (response: 404) for
  file:///tmp/conda-pkgs/noarch/repodata.js
- \ Unable to retrieve repodata (response: 404) for file:///tmp/conda-pkgs/noarch/repodata.jsdone

```
Channels:                                                                                                                                                                                              
 - conda-forge                                                                                                                                                                                         
 - defaults                                                                                                                                                                                            
 - file:///tmp/conda-pkgs                                                                                                                                                                            
Platform: linux-64                                                                                                                                                                                     
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): \ Unable to retrieve repodata (response: 404) for file:///tmp/conda-pkgs/noarch/repodata.js\ Unable to retrieve repodata (response: 404) for file:///tmp/conda-pkgs/noarch/repodata.jsdone                                                                                                                                                                       
Solving environment: done
```

When I run the show-sources command, I am unable to locate the source of this channel and it is no where to be seen in my .condarc files

```
(base) jupyter@oh-my-notebook:~$ conda config --show-sources                                                                                                                                           
==> /opt/conda/.condarc <==                                                                                                                                                                            
channels:                                                                                                                                                                                              
  - conda-forge                                                                                                                                                                                        
  - defaults                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                       
==> /home/jupyter/.condarc <==                                                                                                                                                                         
auto_activate_base: False                                                                                                                                                                              
allow_non_channel_urls: True                                                                                                                                                                           
channels:                                                                                                                                                                                              
  - conda-forge                                                                                                                                                                                        
  - defaults                                                                                                                                                                                           
solver: libmamba                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                                       
==> cmd_line <==                                                                                                                                                                                       
debug: False                                                                                                                                                                                           
json: False
```

I think this file was creating wierd error messages while installing packages. Somehow I managed to convert these [errors to warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60077137/conda-how-to-ignore-if-a-conda-channel-is-not-reachable-ignore-unavailableinva)  and install the packages. However, I still can't figure out as how to get rid of this channel source or where is it coming from in the first place.